# Return pdf byte array WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, pdf, arrays

I am using a web service, WCF, to return a PDF file in byte array format. I was just returning the pdf file that I had in resources like this:

```
public byte[] displayPDF(string pdfName){
    return Service.Properties.Resources.testFile;
}
```

However on the client side when I receive the byte array and write it to a file on my computer using this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 9999999;
var uri = new Uri("http://TestSite.azurewebsites.net/Service.svc/webHttp/displayPDF?pdfName=testFile.pdf");
var response = client.GetAsync(uri);
byte[] byteArray = response.Result.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
var filePath = "C:\\Users\\Admin 1\\Documents\\temp.pdf"; 
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, byteArray);
```

It writes out a PDF file to My Documents, but when I click on it it says can't view PDF because it is not supported file type or it may be corrupted.

I have seen some posts about instead of sending a byte array, to send it using stream. I was wondering if there was any examples on how to do this properly, so that I can write the byte array or stream or whatever you suggest out to a pdf file on the client side, then manually open the file by clicking on it.

**Note:** I am accessing the Web service using REST. So adding a Service Reference is not an option.

Comment: check this article http://www.topwcftutorials.net/2014/03/download-large-file-in-wcf.html

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I cannot add a service reference to the client like your link suggests. I have updated my post accordingly.

Comment: what is the type of "Service" here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the answer, and tried it and it does work. So the answer is that you should be using a Stream instead of a byte array. For anyone else that wants an example I modified my code to this on the server side:

```
public Stream displayPDF(string pdfName)
{
     MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
     ms.Write(Service.Properties.Resources.testFile, 0, Service.Properties.Resources.testFile.Length);
     ms.Position = 0;
     WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/pdf";
     WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=" + pdfName);
     return ms;                         
}
```

And to this on the Client Side:

```
Console.WriteLine("Started"); 
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 9999999;
var uri = new Uri("http://TestSite.azurewebsites.net/Service.svc/webHttp/displayPDF?pdfName=testFile.pdf");
var responseTask = client.GetStreamAsync(uri);
var response = responseTask.Result;
using (System.IO.FileStream output = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\Users\Admin 1\Documents\MyOutput.pdf", FileMode.Create))
{
    response.CopyTo(output);
}
```

Comment: what is the type of "Service" here in "Service.Properties.Resources.testFile"?

Comment: Curious about disposing of the MemoryStream, should you worry about disposing of it here with a "using" statement or try-finally?

Comment: Interesting! Do you have a justification of why a stream is preferable to a byte array?